# How to detect a QGraphicsItem moving performing by mouse?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

I have a child class of QGraphicsItem with Selectable and Movable flags. When I select many  items and moving them, all recieves *itemChange* event. Is there any way to detect in *itemChanged* that mouse's button is still pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the `QApplication::mouseButtons()` [function](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#mouseButtons) that will return the current state of the mouse buttons `Qt::MouseButtons`.

```
Qt::MouseButtons btns = QApplication::mouseButtons();
if (btns & Qt::LeftButton) {
    // The left button is pressed.
    [..]
}
```